# ASP.NET custom function is not called

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code:

```
<asp:TableCell>
    <asp:Label Text="Date of Birth:" Runat="server" cssClass="EditLabel" ID="Label3"/>                                              
</asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell>
    <asp:Textbox id="txtDOB" Runat="server" EnableViewState="True"/>
    <asp:CustomValidator ControlToValidate="txtDOB" ErrorMessage="Date of Birth is not Valid" Runat="server" OnServerValidate="CheckDOB">*</asp:CustomValidator>                        
</asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell>
```

Function is defined as:

```
Protected Sub CheckDOB(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As ServerValidateEventArgs)

  ....

End Sub
```

When I submit the code function is never hit. What is missing here?

Comment: Can you show the markup for the button (assuming that is how the form is being submitted)?

Comment: enter some text in the txtDOB and check

Comment: <asp:TableRow>
     <asp:TableCell>
      <asp:Button `Text="Add Participant" Runat="server"  ID="btnAddParticipant"/>      
     </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>`

Comment: I have 2 Required field validators that work properly when button is pressed.

Comment: I can enter any text in txtDOB without any errors. the Main problem is when I put a breakpoint at Protected Sub CheckDOB, it will never hit.

Comment: Are you clicking a submit button to post the form? Breakpoint will only be hit when you submit on Postback...

Comment: Please ignore my comments for button. It was not being hit because I also have 2 RequiredFields validators and they had no data. So In this case clearly click event of Button is not fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try redefining the handler. Remove `OnServerValidate="CheckDOB"` from Custom ASPX validator markup and define handler in VB like this:

```
Protected Sub CheckDOB(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles CustomValidator1.ServerValidate

End Sub
```

Comment: OK, Adding the handler directly make it work. I have no idea why for this case it needed a handler explicitly.

Now IF I have valid data for First Name and Last Name and press the button then CheckDOB is called. You get a +1 here. But I need to know why some controls like button do not need an explicit event handler.

Comment: Your code worked without explicit handler in my environment. but then I simple copy/pasted your code from here. I guess your page's markup is a lot more complex, so, something must be interfering. As a rule of the thumb in VB.NET code I always use `Handles` approach.

Comment: By the way, if you want to handle 'no data' scenario - add `ValidateEmptyText="true"` to your Custom Validator attributes

Comment: You said my code worked when you tried it. no my code is not complex. Just try this also :

Add a textbox name it Fname and add a requiredfiled validator for it. Now see if Customvalidator is still working. I appreciate your time for testing this.

Comment: I don't see a ValidateEmptyText attribute. I Guess it is not part of framework1.1 which I am limited to, but that's OK.

Comment: Still works with multiple texboxes and validators in my case. But then again I am using .NET 3.5, maybe 1.1. is part of the problem

Comment: Thanks, glad I was able to help. And you're right `ValidateEmptyText` first appeared in .NET 2.0 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.validateemptytext(v=vs.80).aspx). I know it's not always an option, but if there's any chance try pushing to upgrade to a newer framework